# How can we continue to use the Redmine service hook with the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I just read today that the merger of Fabric (Crashlytics) and Firebase will take place soon and result in the end of Fabric Crashlytics as of 2019.

[The roadmap](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap) says they are working on JIRA and PagerDuty service hooks. I assume this means that all other service hooks are not compatible with the coming Firebase Crashlytics SDK.

Is there any SDK or API that we can use to create a new service hook using the new Firebase Crashlytics platform? How can we be sure that Crashlytics will still post bug reports to Redmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric and Firebase here. Yes, not all of the current service hooks in Fabric will be migrated over. You can use Cloud [Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/extend-with-cloud-functions) from Firebase in order to configure notifications in various other services.

For example, on a new issue, you could use the `onNew()` call:

```
exports.sendOnNewIssue = functions.crashlytics.issue().onNew(async (issue) => {
  // ...
});
```

and then use something to similar [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/crashlytics-integration/jira-issue) but for JIRA. Sorry I can't provide a fully working sample as I don't currently have Redmine setup.

Comment: Neat, thanks Mike. I have implemented [this](https://github.com/BenoitDuffez/Firebase-Crashlytics-Redmine), please let me know whether you think this would do. I have tested it successfully on local with a mock issue: it works. I don't know how to propagate the environment to production? I've never done any functions development so I'm a bit lost here. Also, I don't know if I can test this without installing the new SDK?

Comment: Yes, overall, that looks like a good approach. Here's how you would want to push it live: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/

Comment: Hi @BenoitDuffez, this is really cool! Please consider adding it to the Cloud Functions Samples repo: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples.

Comment: Will do. Any chance this would be integrated in the official Firebase service hooks instead of Cloud Functions? Redmine has a clean REST JSON API. As you can see from my repo, the actual code is less than a hundred lines.

Comment: @buser: not sure this what you requested for, but here's my contribution: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/pull/477